# Jquery ajax call not working android 4.X web view

Tags: jquery, cordova, android-webview

I'm developing a Phonegap Android application.
I'm using JqueryMobile framework with Phonegap.
Jquery ajax calls wokring fine in the android 2.3.2

But the same app is not working in android 4.1, 4.2 versions
The same happens if i test it in emulator. working in 2.3 emulator and not working in 4.2 emulator.

Following is the js code

```
 function loadData(){
        alert('function called');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BROWSECOURSE_URI, // url assigned to this variable
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'qry_mode=Browsecourse&limit=100&start=0',
    success: function(msg){

        alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
    },
    error:function (msg) {
       alert('remote server is not responding.please try after some time');
     }
    });
}
```

When i run the app in 4.1 device only the first alert is showing.

I googled about this issue `"jquery ajax call not working in android"`.
All are saying, using pure XMLHttpRequest solved this problem.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/wdQ4ga5Lkp0/4zZzh-UYNJ8J.

If this is the case, i have to rewrite the entire app.

How others are developing phonegap android apps for the 4.x versions of android devices.